# Java - RegEx is failing to accept previous expressions

Tags: java, regex

First of all, sorry for possible mistakes, English is not my first language.

I use RegEx in Java to receive files on a server, today I use this expression `^.*VRMP.FAT.*$` to receive files with names like these (and it works fine)

```
083.080523.VRMP.FAT.VLP.ELBT.04.1908

083.080514.VRMP.FAT.ATT.ELMT.01.2208
```

I needed to change the expression because now I'm receiving files that have a difference at the end of the name and these MUST NOT be received.
The new files have names like these:

```
083.080523.VRMP.FAT.VLP.ELBT.04.1908_FALLBACK_D2.zip

083.080523.VRMP.FAT.VLP.ELBT.04.1908_FALLBACK_D4.zip
```

So, my new expression looks like this:

```
^.*VRMP.FAT.*[^(?!\_FALLBACK_(D2|D4).zip)]$
```

This new expression worked perfectly to reject the new files, but it's not working to receive the files that were already received before (the first two examples, which do not contain `_FALLBACK_D2.zip` at the end).

I'm using Pattern and Matcher objects to validate expressions and filenames:

`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex.toLowerCase());`

`Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fileName.toLowerCase());`

The method `matcher.matches()` is returning false for both the old and new filenames, and I need it to return false only for the new names that contain the FALLBACK ending.

Why it stopped working for the previous files? Any guesses?

And what do I need to fix to meet both conditions?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is the lookahead inside a character class?

Comment: Character classes treat everything inside as simple characters.  So `[^(?!x)]` just means none of those individual characters - the lookahead is NOT being done.  What you really want is `^.*VRMP.FAT.*(?<!_FALLBACK_(D2|D4).zip)$` which is a negative lookbehind just before the $ so the string isn't accepted if it ends with _FALLBACK_(D2|D4).zip  https://regex101.com/r/rMJvNp/1

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern uses a negated character class at the end, that matches a single character other than one of `[^(?!\_FALLBACK_(D2|D4).zip)]` so if your line ends with `4` is does not match.

If you remove the square brackets and the `^` it would still match all lines, as the `.*` would first match until the end of the string and the negative lookahead asserting will always be true.

What you could do is use the negative lookahead at the position right after `FAT` to check that the string from that point on does not end with the FALLBACK part.

```
^.*?VRMP\.FAT(?!.*_FALLBACK_D[24]\.zip$).*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XzLc0K/1).

Or you can match the more precise pattern without a lookahead assertion at all:

```
^\d+\.\d+\.VRMP\.FAT\.[A-Z]+\.[A-Z]+\.\d+\.\d+$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ufehj0/1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I tested it with your suggestion and it worked as I needed. Thank you very much!